# Compilation problems while learning React DND

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-dnd

I am starting to learn React Drag and Drop from http://react-dnd.github.io/react-dnd/docs-tutorial.html

But I am having problems understanding the tutorial. Next are all the files I created but at compilation I get:

```
 dragDropBundle.js:830 Warning: Failed prop type: The prop 
  `connectDropTarget` is marked as required in `BoardSquare`, but its value is `undefined`.
   in BoardSquare (created by Board)
   in Board (created by DragDropContext(Board))
   in DragDropContext(Board)
```

and

```
dragDropBundle.js:31408 Uncaught TypeError: connectDropTarget is not a function
  at BoardSquare.render (dragDropBundle.js:31408)
  at dragDropBundle.js:16370
```

Can someone explain me please what is wrong? I am reading this tutorial several times and hitting the wall with it.

Here it is the content of my file `entry.js` from where my program starts:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Square from "./Square.jsx";
import Board from "./Board.jsx";
import Knight from "./Knight.jsx";

import { observe } from "./Game.jsx";
import { canMoveKnight, moveKnight } from "./Game.jsx";

const rootEl = document.getElementById("root");

observe(knightPosition =>
  ReactDOM.render(<Board knightPosition={knightPosition} />, rootEl)
);
```

Here it is the content of my file `Board.jsx`:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { DragDropContext } from "react-dnd";
import HTML5Backend from "react-dnd-html5-backend";

import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import Square from "./Square.jsx";
import Knight from "./Knight.jsx";
import { canMoveKnight, moveKnight } from "./Game.jsx";
import { BoardSquare } from "./BoardSquare.jsx";

export class Board extends Component {
  renderPiece(x, y) {
    const [knightX, knightY] = this.props.knightPosition;
    if (x === knightX && y === knightY) {
      return <Knight />;
    }
  }

  renderSquare(i) {
    const x = i % 8;
    const y = Math.floor(i / 8);
    return (
      <div key={i} style={{ width: "12.5%", height: "12.5%" }}>
        <BoardSquare x={x} y={y}>
          {this.renderPiece(x, y)}
        </BoardSquare>
      </div>
    );
  }

  handleSquareClick(toX, toY) {
    if (canMoveKnight(toX, toY)) {
      moveKnight(toX, toY);
    }
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.props.knightPosition);
    const squares = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 64; i++) {
      squares.push(this.renderSquare(i));
    }

    return (
      <div
        style={{
          width: "100%",
          height: "100%",
          display: "flex",
          flexWrap: "wrap"
        }}
      >
        {squares}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

Board.propTypes = {
  knightPosition: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.number.isRequired).isRequired
};

export default DragDropContext(HTML5Backend)(Board);
```

Here it is the content of my file `Knight.jsx`:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { ItemTypes } from "./Constants.jsx";
import { DragSource } from "react-dnd";

const knightSource = {
  beginDrag(props) {
    return {};
  }
};

function collect(connect, monitor) {
  return {
    connectDragSource: connect.dragSource(),
    isDragging: monitor.isDragging()
  };
}

class Knight extends Component {
  render() {
    const { connectDragSource, isDragging } = this.props;
    return connectDragSource(
      <div
        style={{
          opacity: isDragging ? 0.5 : 1,
          fontSize: 25,
          fontWeight: "bold",
          cursor: "move"
        }}
      >
        ♘
      </div>
    );
  }
}

Knight.propTypes = {
  connectDragSource: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  isDragging: PropTypes.bool.isRequired
};

export default DragSource(ItemTypes.KNIGHT, knightSource, collect)(Knight);
```

Here it is the content of my file `Square.jsx`:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

export default class Square extends Component {
  render() {
    const { black } = this.props;
    const fill = black ? "black" : "white";
    const stroke = black ? "white" : "black";

    return (
      <div
        style={{
          backgroundColor: fill,
          color: stroke,
          width: "100%",
          height: "100%"
        }}
      >
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

Square.propTypes = {
  black: PropTypes.bool
};
```

Here it is the content of my file: `BoardSquare.jsx`

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import Square from "./Square.jsx";
import { canMoveKnight, moveKnight } from "./Game.jsx";
import { ItemTypes } from "./Constants.jsx";
import { DropTarget } from "react-dnd";

const squareTarget = {
  drop(props) {
    moveKnight(props.x, props.y);
  }
};

function collect(connect, monitor) {
  return {
    connectDropTarget: connect.dropTarget(),
    isOver: monitor.isOver()
  };
}

export class BoardSquare extends Component {
  render() {
    const { x, y, connectDropTarget, isOver } = this.props;
    const black = (x + y) % 2 === 1;

    return connectDropTarget(
      <div
        style={{
          position: "relative",
          width: "100%",
          height: "100%"
        }}
      >
        <Square black={black}>{this.props.children}</Square>
        {isOver && (
          <div
            style={{
              position: "absolute",
              top: 0,
              left: 0,
              height: "100%",
              width: "100%",
              zIndex: 1,
              opacity: 0.5,
              backgroundColor: "yellow"
            }}
          />
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

BoardSquare.propTypes = {
  x: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
  y: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
  connectDropTarget: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  isOver: PropTypes.bool.isRequired
};

export default DropTarget(ItemTypes.KNIGHT, squareTarget, collect)(BoardSquare);
```

Comment: please format your code nicely before posting and try to only include the relevant code, not everything, to enable SO users to more easily help you.

Comment: I understand.... the problem is that the tutorial itself (at least the way it is originally  presented) is so confusing that the connections between the files seem to be relevant. I expended a lot of hours getting to the results in this question. Sorry for the length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error is caused by this props type setting:

```
BoardSquare.propTypes = {
  // ...
  connectDropTarget: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  //                               ^^^^^^^^^^^ property connectDropTarget is market as required
  // ...
};
```

Which marks `connectDropTarget` as a required prop in `BoardSquare`.

What should happen is that, because you wrap `BoardSquare` into a `DropTarget`, the `DropTarget` knows to set the value for `connectDropTarget` in the props of `BoardSquare` through the `collect` function.

However, what you are doing is using the barebones `BoardSquare` function, not the one wrapped in `DropTarget`.

```
// Board.jsx
import {BoardSquare} from './BoardSquare.jsx';
//     ^           ^ you are importing BoardSquare, not DropTarget(...)(BoardSquare)
```

This should be:

```
// Board.jsx
import BoardSquare from './BoardSquare.jsx';
```

So this means that, since you're not using the component wrapped in `DropTarget`, nothing is calling the `collect` function and thus nothing is setting the `connectDropTarget` prop.

To clean things up, you can probably remove the `export` of the barebones class from `BoardSquare` and only export the class wrapped in `DropTarget`:

```
// BoardSquare.jsx
export class BoardSquare extends Component {
// ^^^ remove this export statement
```

Comment: I will try this. The original code from the tutorial keeps the isRequired condition

Comment: @JoseCabreraZuniga I found the problem, it's not what I initially said

Comment: Man, you did it!

Comment: @JoseCabreraZuniga keep pushing my man, things will get easier over time, you got this :)